# implementing collapse in angular using ElementRef

Tags: angular

I need to implement basic collapse in angular using elementRef but i am finding difficulty understing and the HTML contain i have is a ngfor i need to send the index value to the click event so that it takes the ID of the

Here is the link
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_animate

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
// i have replaced this 
var in_Angular = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible'));


var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    console.log(this.classList);
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;  //where this value coming from
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

i think addEventListener is not required because in angular we have click event. how do i use elementRef in the example.

Comment: Why do you want to use ElementRef?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use powerful libraries like:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples

but if you need more control: in angular (specially > 2) you have to think different. It is not a good way to follow javascript-like approach to solve problems. we have to read more about these frameworks before starting the project. 
In fact you should forget getElementsByClassName, querySelectorAll, content.style.maxHeight and all these stuffs. in Angular there is almost a whole new concept.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you build a custom directive and utilize the @HostListener that is naturally provided by angular